# Sql Multi Linked List

Tags: php, sql, linked-list, iteration

I'm trying to display the order in which certain steps can be taken.  Some steps can be taken simultaneously, while others have to follow in a particular order.  I have the data already in an SQL table, and just want to be able to pull this into a PHP array or something so I can print it out.

The data is stored in 1 sql table, with 2 fields.  The first is stat (which is the number of this block), the second is prereq, which identifies the predecessor (which would be some other stat).  If the prereq field is null, this is the starting point. The ending point is when there is no other rows.

1st example:

```
status_number    prereq
-------------    -------
3                NULL
4                3
5                4
6                4
7                5
7                6
8                7
```

Looks like this conceptually:

[image]

I'm thinking to visually print this, first I want to get the data into a PHP array, with nested arrays for where I would have 2 stats vertically (in this case, 5 & 6).  So, the array would look like: (3,4,(5,6),7,8).  How can I get the data into this form?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, it may need some tweaking though

```
/* fetch the status_numbers and prereqs */
$query = "SELECT status_number, prereq FROM status";
$rs = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)) {
    $ids[] = $row[0];
    $fwd[$row[0]][] = $row[1];
}

/* find the endpoint(s) */
$ends = array();
foreach ($ids as $search) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($fwd as $deps) {
        if (in_array($search, $deps)) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($found)
        continue;
    $ends[] = $search;
}

/* sort the deps so we can string compare */
foreach ($fwd as &$deps)
    asort($deps);

    /* recursive resolve function */
function resolve($fwd, $id, &$output) {
    if (!is_null($id))
        array_unshift($output, $id);

    $count = count($fwd[$id]);
    if ($count == 0)
        return;

    if ($count > 1) {
        $subs = array();
        $groups = array();
        foreach ($fwd[$id] as $dep)
            $subs[$dep] = implode(',', $fwd[$dep]);

        foreach ($subs as $dep => $str1) {
            unset($subs[$index]);
            foreach ($subs as $index => $str2)
                if ($str1 == $str2) {
                    unset($subs[$index]);
                    $groups[$str1][] = $index;
                }
        }

        foreach ($groups as $ids => $group) {
            array_unshift($output, $group);
            $ids = explode(',', $ids);
            foreach ($ids as $id)
                resolve($fwd, $id, $output);
        }
    }
    else {
        resolve($fwd, $fwd[$id][0], $output);
    }
}

$output = array();
foreach ($ends as $end)
    resolve($fwd, $end, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 3
  [1] => 4
  [2] => Array
      (
          [0] => 5
          [1] => 6
      )

  [3] => 7
  [4] => 8
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, though I have to admit I haven't tested it:

```
# get the data - let the DB handle the ordering
$sql = "SELECT status_number,prereq FROM t ORDER BY prereq, status_number"
$res = mysql_query($sql);

# initialize pre-loop stuff
$status_array = array();
$prev_prereq = '';

# loop through the results
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
  # check if the prereq is the same as the previous result, and if so...
  if ($prev_prereq == $row['prereq'])
  {
    # look at the last element in the array
    end($status_array);
    $lastIndex = key($status_array);

    # if it's not an array
    if (! is_array($status_array[lastIndex]))
    {
      #  make it one that contains the value that was in that spot
      $v = $status_array[lastIndex]
      $status_array[lastIndex] = array();
      status_array[$lastIndex][] = $v;
    }

    # then append the status to that array
    status_array[$lastIndex][] = $row['status_number'];

  } else
  # just append the latest status the the end of the status array
  {
    $status_array[] = $row['status_number'];
    $prev_prereq = $row['prereq'];
  }
}
```